# Return an empty list on @OneToMany SpringBoot - Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting null when using relationship in hibernate.
Here is my code
**User entity**

```
@Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private long userId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",targetEntity=LoginHistory.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<LoginHistory> loginHistory = new ArrayList<LoginHistory>();
```

**LoginHistory Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login_history")
public class LoginHistory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="userId",referencedColumnName="id")
    private User user;
```

To get login history details

```
@Override
    public List<LoginHistory> getLoginHistory(User user) {
        List<LoginHistory> lst = user.getLoginHistory();
        return lst;
    }
```

I am getting an empty list. Please help

Comment: Could you please also share with us, how you are using these entities? Perhaps a spring boot test that demonstrates the behavior. At the moment I would say, the user simply has no login history.

Comment: Login history table has one column with the user id and has some data.

Answer (score 0):

it is working as designed as you are accessing an entity which is lazy loaded.Use the below like code to get the login history if you continue to keep the lazy loading on.

```
 User user = getByKey(id);
            if(user!=null){
                Hibernate.initialize(user.getUserProfiles());
            }
```